# jquery alerts several times

Tags: jquery

Why does the following code cause jquery to alert 3 times?

`.note_text` is a class within `.note_content`.

```
   $('.note_content').click(function()  {
      var note_text = $(this).find(".note_text");
      $(note_text).focus();

      // save its contents:
      var original_text = note_text.html(); 

      $(note_text).blur(function() {
         if (note_text.html() !== original_text)
         {
            alert('Not the same');
         }   
      });

   });
```

When the outer div is highlighted I want the inner div (which contains the text) to be focused on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(note_text).blur(function() {
```

That line binds an event handler. Every time the element is blurred, that handler will run. You assign a new handler every time the click handler on `.note_content` is triggered, so you will have multiple alerts.

The way around this is to store data on the element, rather than in a closure.

```
$('.note_content').click(function()  {
    $(this).find('.note_text').data('oldText', node_text.html()).focus();
});
$('.note_text').blur(function() {
    if ($(this).html() !== $(this).data('oldText')) {
        alert('not the same');
    }
});
```

This way the handlers are only bound once.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to action bubbling.

Adding a `event.stopPropagation();` should fix that.

(remember - `$('.note_content').click(function(event)  {...`)